# Regular expression quiz

Tags: regex

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a good regular expression to extract contents from some texts like this.

```
2 years ago -> 6 months ago
```

which has two elements `2 years ago` and `6 months ago` separated by two contiguous characters `->`.

It is easy if the separator is single character (for example, `1 year = 12 months` is easy to extract from by the regular expression `([^=]+)=([^=]+)` ) but I don't know such a case that the length of the separator is more than 1.

Comment: Why not split with `->`? No regex is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for a good advice!

Comment: Yeah, easier than anything like [`\b(?!\W)([^-]*(?:-(?!>)[^-]*)*)->([^-]*(?:-(?!>)[^-]*)*)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yN0iC5/1)

Comment: Wow! crazy!! I didn't know I was trying such a crazy task! Thanks!

Comment: Well, it can be done easier, but still, [`\b(?<!\w)(.*?)->((?:(?!->).)*)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yN0iC5/2) is clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you well, you can use:

```
(.*)->(.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS8iV2/1)**

Anyway, as [Wiktor Stribzew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) pointed in this comment... you might want just to split by `->`

Comment: Thank you. 

It works well with `2 years ago -> 6 months ago`. but  in the case that  `->` appears more than once, I want the regular expression not to  match it.
For example, `1 -> 2 -> 3` should be regarded as not match.

Comment: > you might want just to split by ->

It might be true... I'm writing a simple parser program and it can be easy if everything can be written with pairs of a regexp and operation when it matches.